# Accessing @props from magnificPopup in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, frontend

In the render function of a reactJS class, I have the following button, it triggers `confirmRemove`

```html
<a href='#'
   className='content-icon'
   title='Remove entry'
   onClick={this.confirmRemove}>
   <%= image_tag("form/remove.png") %>
</a>
```

In `confirmRemove` (it's coffee-script), a magnificPop is created:

```coffee
confirmRemove: (e) ->
  e.preventDefault()

  $.magnificPopup.open(
      {
          items: {
              type: 'inline',
              src: $(
                '<div className="white-popup">
                   <h4>Do you really want to remove this entry from the playlist?</h4>
                   <button id="test-popup-no">No</button>
                   <button id="test-popup-yes">Yes</button>
                 </div>'
              )
          },
          type: 'inline',
          midClick: true
      }
  )

  $('#test-popup-yes').click ->
    $.magnificPopup.close()
    $.ajax
      type:     'PUT'
      dataType: 'JSON'
      url:      "/xxx/#{@props.xxxId}/remove_entry"
      data:
        '_method': 'PUT'
        'xxx_id': @props.id
      beforeSend: =>
        $.status_message 'Removing xxx', 0
        @props.onDeleteStart()
      success: (data) =>
        $.success_message 'Successfully removed xxx'
        @props.onDeleteCommit()
      error: (data) =>
        $.error_message 'Error removing xxx'
        @props.onDeleteFailure()
```

But on clicking the `test-popup-yes` button, I got `detailed error: TypeError: this.props is undefined`

I think this is a scoping issue, any idea on accessing @props inside the on-click function.

Comment: You may want to mention you're using CoffeeScript (I think??) It took me a while to parse what was going on.

Comment: @gnack mentioned coffee-script, thanks for letting me know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, this is a scoping issue. Since `this` frequently changes when you change the scope by calling a new function, you can't access the original value by using it.

You can solve this in 2 ways.

1. Using fat arrow to bind `this` with the outer scope in your click handler.

example:

```
$('#test-popup-yes').click =>
```

2. Aliasing `this` so that you still have access to the original value of this.

example:

```
confirmRemove: (e) ->
  e.preventDefault()

  that = this //aliasing this to that

  ...

  $('#test-popup-yes').click ->
    $.magnificPopup.close()
    $.ajax
      type:     'PUT'
      dataType: 'JSON'
      url:      "/xxx/#{that.props.xxxId}/remove_entry"
      data:
        '_method': 'PUT'
        'xxx_id': that.props.id
      beforeSend: =>
        $.status_message 'Removing xxx', 0
        that.props.onDeleteStart()
      success: (data) =>
        $.success_message 'Successfully removed xxx'
        that.props.onDeleteCommit()
      error: (data) =>
        $.error_message 'Error removing xxx'
        that.props.onDeleteFailure()
```